# не получается установить соединение моего django проекта и базы данных mongodb(развернута локально)

Tags: python, django, mongodb

установил mongodb локальную версию. Нашел статью в которой указано, что начать работать с базой данных mongo можно посредством mongodb-engine.
Следую документации я импортировал следующие библиотеки:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine
```

Далее следуя этой же документации я вношу корректировки в файл settings.py моего проекта django:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default' : {
      'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
      'NAME' : 'my_database'
   }
}
```

На это я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
File "C:\Users\root\PycharmProjects\SpaceFarm.tech\venv\lib\site-packages\django_mongodb_engine\base.py", line 272
    raise ImproperlyConfigured, exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

При этом если вернуться к работе с предыдущей базой данных sqlite3 и соответствующим настройкам все работает корректно (Настройки:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Что нужно сделать для того, чтобы начать работать с Mongodb???

Comment: проверьте версии

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325288/raise-improperlyconfigured-exc-info1-exc-info2

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, подскажите, а как правильно прописать это в настройках? Я установил себе пакет django-mongodb-engine-py3 и перешел в документацию к данной библиотеке. Настройки там прописаны так же. Все равно выдает туже ошибку